# How to format the whole sheet depending on a cell value

Tags: excel

The title may be a little misleading, anyway, this is what I'm trying to do.

I have this sheet that is supposed to show employee leave dates and mark them in the sheet with a color depending on the department the employees work at.
So what I'm trying to do is what the image says below
[Image link here, since I don't have enough points to embed images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wskak.png)

So, on the left we have Engineer, Sales, IT, and Engineer, and want I want to do is color the cells on the right that have **'v'** on them a color depending on the department.

On the image I did it manually, just for demonstration purpose, Engineer's should automatically become green, Sales, a different color, IT a different color, and so on. And this must be done on the whole sheet as more employees will be added to the sheet. And whenever I enter the value 'v' to an empty cell it gets colored based on the employee's department.

Comment: Look into Conditional Formatting, You will create a rule for each department.

Comment: Yeah I'm looking at Conditional Formatting, though I don't know how to create the formula. Since I need to check what the current row's department is, and whether it has the value 'v' in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to go look into the conditional formatting options for the table.

To achieve what you want, you'll want to make one rule for each department with your own conditional rule that goes something like:

```
=AND($A2 = "Engineer", F2 = "V")
```

F2 being the cell, A being your first column, and 2 being your first row.

Comment: I tried this, this is my formula `="AND($A6=""Engineer"", G6=""v"")"` and this is what it applies to `=$G$6:$K$11` but it doesn't seem to be working. A6 being the first row, and G6 being the cell

Comment: And when I input this as formula `=AND($A6="Engineer", G6="v")` Excel is telling me that there's something wrong with the formula, but when I add the double quotations "", it doesn't show an error, but doesn't work

Comment: The reason it wasn't working for me was because my regional settings were not set to English and that was causing errors with Excel, check this for more details: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother/error-display-window-theres-a-problem-with-this/fd41b58f-de65-44a4-a086-cc829101c214